# Are there any side effects of changing the root level of log4net in c#

Tags: c#, log4net

I have changed my `log` level from `info` to `debug`.

But I am quite confuse that are there any side effect of changing like this , except that I will receive more `log` information.

Thanks

Comment: additionally you'll get higher cpu load

Comment: Since root logger is really root, it filters events for all other loggers. So if you'll increase the level back to the  `info`, then all other loggers will not log debug levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely potential side affects of changing your log levels from INFO to DEBUG.  For example if you have a highly concurrent WCF or Web Service and it's logging to a single log file the writing of the log file could severely affect overall performance.  We've had this happen several times in a production system where we have a highly concurrent back-end service.

I think this also depends on what type of appenders you are using.  If you are using the database appender for example this could greatly affect performance as you are doing database inserts for every log statement.

In addition to this if your code is using statements like the following you could potentially expose issues with your logging if you've never enabled debug before:

```
if(log.IsDebugEnabled)
{
    log.DebugFormat("blah {0}", someVariable);
}
```